# Change OpenGL coordinates to window coordinates using gluProject method

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to Change OpenGL coordinates to window coordinates using gluProject method. Here is a part of my code:

```
{
    float test = m_nusha.GetExtremeLeftPicturePoint();
        float test1 = m_nusha.GetExtremeRightPicturePoint();
        float test2 = m_nusha.GetExtremeTopPicturePoint();
        float test3 = m_nusha.GetExtremeBottomPicturePoint();

    gluProject(test, holeY, holeZ, mvm, projm, viewport, &leftPictureSide, &holeY1, &holeZ1);
    gluProject(test1, holeY, holeZ, mvm, projm, viewport, &rightPictureSide, &holeY1, &holeZ1);
    gluProject(holeX, test2, holeZ, mvm, projm, viewport, &holeX1, &topPictureSide, &holeZ1);
    gluProject(holeX, test3, holeZ, mvm, projm, viewport, &holeX1, &bottomPictureSide, &holeZ1);
}
```

But why are leftPictureSide and rightPictureSide equal(543) if test and test1 have a differends signs? Is this because gluProject-method accepts first argument with GLdouble type(Is GLdouble an unsigned type?).And why are topPictureSide and bottomPictureSide equal(142) if test2 and test3 variables are quite different? How to fix it?

Comment: There are no such thing as OpenGL coordinates. `gluProject (...)` takes object-space coordinates and transforms them into window-space. Every coordinate space in-between is an "OpenGL coordinate."

Comment: Regarding `GLdouble`, that is a double-precision floating-point type. Like virtually all other floating-point types, it is signed.